# Test a Node.js Application with Mocha including ES6-Modules in Dependencies

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, mocha.js, bpmn.io

I want to test my simple **Node.js** (v14.15.4) application with **Mocha** (v8.2.1).
I also include **Babel** to compile the ES6 modules in my code.

In particular, I use `"@babel/core" (v7.12.10)`, `"babel/register" (v7.12.10)` to use the compiler with mocha, and  `"@babel/preset-env" (v7.12.11)` for ES6 module support.

Everything works fine, until I include an external dependency in my code. In my case, I want to use `bpmn-js (v8.2.0)` which itself is ready for the use with ES6 modules (https://bpmn.io/blog/posts/2018-migrating-to-es-modules.html).

My project structure is as follows:

```
- bpmn
    - index.js
- node_modules
    - ...
- babel.config.json
- index.js
- index.test.js
- package.json
```

The files are depicted below:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/register index.test.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "8.2.1",
    "@babel/core": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/register": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bpmn-js": "8.2.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**babel.config.json**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

**index.js**

```
export {
    default
  } from './bpmn';
```

**bpmn/index.js**

```
//import { Viewer } from 'bpmn-js';

export default (str) => {
    return str.toUpperCase();
};
```

**index.test.js**

```
import toUpperCase from './index';

const assert = require('assert');

describe('The module toUpperCase', () => {
  it('should transform my test string', () => {
    assert.strictEqual(toUpperCase('test'), 'TEST');
  });
});
```

As stated, everything works fine when running `npm run test`.
However, if I include the comment in line 1 in the **bpmn/index.js** file,
the error below occurs. It seems that babel compiles my local project files, but ignores the external dependencies, i.e. `bpmn-js` in that case

```
\node_modules\bpmn-js\index.js:1
export {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Module._compile (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\bpmn\/index.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._compile (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\/index.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._compile (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\/index.test.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._compile (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:20:12)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:33:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:431:19)
    at singleRun (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:125:15)
    at exports.runMocha (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:190:10)
    at Object.exports.handler (D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:362:11)
    at D:\Code\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:241:49
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your approach. The first one, really fundamental, is that you are trying to import **bpmn-js** inside a Node.js process. This package can only be run in a browser as it **depends on the DOM Document** being available. You are never going to be able to do this. The other problem is, as you correctly figured out, that bpmn-js uses ES6 module syntax. By default, packages found in the **node_modules** directory are **ignored** by @babel/register that you require. In other words, they are not transpiled. You could configure @babel/register to make an exemption for bpmn-js and transpile it but your import would still fail with something like:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```